# Visual Studio 2022 Setup Project changes timestamp of all files

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-setup-proje

I recently moved from VS 2019 to VS 2022 and installed setup project extension for VS 2022 version:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2022InstallerProjects

The problem is that when I install binaries now, all files in the installation folder have the current date/time (with VS 2019, only the modified DLLs / EXE file would have the current date/time, all other DLLS [from 3rd party libraries] would retain their original date/time).

I have tried to uninstall & re-install the extension + delete and recreate the setup project, to no avail.  These are 64-bit Winform apps, .NET 4.6.1.

The csproj & sln files are identical, so it is unlikely that the problem is related to those files (or the project references, since they live in the csproj files).

Also, I tried opening the solution in VS 2019 again (even though the setup project extension is only for 2022) and it built and installed fine, without changing the timestamp of all the files.

*How can I make this work with VS 2022 so that when I install new binaries, only the modified files get a new timestamp?*

Comment: The download page you linked to clearly has a "Q&A" section for you to talk to the right people.

Answer (score 1):

I propose you do to use e.g. [lessmsi](https://github.com/activescott/lessmsi) and check how the file got
packed into the .msi. While this may not provide the final answer to
your question, it will tell you about the root cause of the issue.

I ran into the very same issue. My case also is a WinForms App,
targetting .NET Framework 4.8, same issue. The following screenshots show the binary in question extracted from the .msi: [VS2022 setup project packs with changed time stamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDSAv.png) whereas [VS2017 setup project preserves time stamp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5cho2.png).
So in my case the issue apparently is caused by the VS2022 setup project which packs with changed time stamp. I have created a [ticket at Microsoft](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Installer-Projects-2022-reset-the-time-s/10233114), hoping they get this issue fixed.